# Displaying a text right of an image as if the image was bigger than it really is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following statements to display an image. If it is bigger then it is resized to a smaller size while keeping the aspect ratio. But if it is smaller it shall NOT be resized. It works theoretically quite well that is until I put in an image with a width of only 100px. Then the text is displayed at a distance of 100px from the left side (aka immediately after the image).>

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: justify">
        <div width='300px'>
            <img src='mypic.jpg' align='left' style="max-width:'300px'; max-height:'300px'" width='auto'/>
        </div>
        <h2>
            mytextasdfasdfasdfasdffs
        </h2>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now my question here is: How can I manage to achieve that it looks like there is always a place usage of 300 px width even if the image is smaller?

Comment: Use attr `style`, (`style="width:300px"`)

Comment: There are no `max-width` and `max-height` HTML attributes. Adding to that, the HTML4 `width` attribute isn't valid on a `div` element.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly tnx corrected the example (copy and paste error from converting things that I set via css and javascript into a html only example^^)

Comment: @waki tried taht already with the div itself (if done on the image it works but then again the picture is enalrged what I dont want), but doesnt work there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I undestand it correctly

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: justify">
        <div style="min-width:300px; min-height: 300px;"><!-- always display 300px box -->
            <img src='mypic.jpg' align='left' style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px; width: auto; height: auto;" />
        </div>
        <h2>
            mytextasdfasdfasdfasdffs
        </h2>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
    </div>
</body>
```

UPDATE with float:

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: justify">
        <div style="min-width:300px; min-height: 300px; float: left;"><!-- always display 300px box on the left -->
            <img src='mypic.jpg' align='left' style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px; width: auto; height: auto;" />
        </div>
        <h2>
            mytextasdfasdfasdfasdffs
        </h2>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
        asdasfsfsfdsgsfgsfgsfgsfg<br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that setting width and height to auto does NOT keep aspect ratio in Internet Explorer!!! (not sure what versions) You must use JS

Comment: Sure about that? I tried it with IE11 and width: auto and setting max-width and max-height worked well so far with all tests I made with too big and too small images

Comment: tried your code out. if I copy yours over mine the h2,... are displayed way below the image instead of flowing around it. When I leave the min-height out it becomes the same situation as originally again

Comment: By IE I mean IE10 and older. IE11 is not (internally) "MSIE 11" but "Trident 7" :)

Comment: I've added another version with float to display the image on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/9a6ptaqf/

Comment: yepp saw it that one works fine. Do you have any idea why both minheight AND minwidth have to be set to have any effect? (original image is 85 x 50 and in my local test I use min-width 800px)

Comment: ah that question solved itself.....was a typing error when I put your answer into my testcode^^'  tnx a lot

Comment: It works even with only min-height (http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/9a6ptaqf/1/) or min-width (http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/9a6ptaqf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  <img src='mypic.jpg' align='left' max-width='300px' max-height='300px' width='auto'/>
```

to

```
<img src='mypic.jpg' align='left' style="max-width:300px; max-height:300px; width:auto"/>
```

Comment: Hi even with the change it is still displayed the same way for me. Tested it with both chrome and IE11)